# how to store date array using foreach loop into a variable in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
die("cannot connect" . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test",$con);
$sql = "SELECT Renewal_Date FROM ilist";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$result_array = array();
echo "<table border=2 >
<tr>

   <th>Renewal_Date</th>
</tr>";
  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
  echo"<tr>";

  echo "<td>" . $record['Renewal_Date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";


}
echo "</table>";
   $date3=array();
   $todayDate = date('m/d/Y');
   $date1 = new DateTime($todayDate);
   $date2 = new DateTime($record['Renewal_Date']);
     foreach($date2 as $date3)
       $interval = $date1->diff($date3);
    echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d."        days ";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I've fetched renewal date list into an array $record, now i need to store each date in
a variable using foreach and that variable will be used to find difference with present date.
    How to do this?

```
regards Sanji
```

Comment: What is the error? What is not working?

Comment: format mismatch error was there. Shankar Damodaran's reply is working fine. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite like this... [You don't need a `foreach` construct , instead do the thing inside the same `while` loop itself]

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
  echo"<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $record['Renewal_Date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $todayDate = date('m/d/Y');
  $date1 = new DateTime($todayDate);
  $date2 = new DateTime($record['Renewal_Date']);
  $interval = $date1->diff($date2); //  I assume renewal date should be greater , so it must be $date2->diff($date1);
  echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d."        days ";
}
```

Comment: And about renewal date, it should be greater than today's date else we must increment fine amount. This is for a library system.